# How to write a JSON schema for array of objects?

Tags: ruby, json, jsonschema

My JSON string would be formatted as:

```
{
    "count":3,
    "data":[
        {
            "a":{"ax":1}
        },
        {
            "b":{"bx":2}
        },
        {
            "c":{"cx":4}
        }
    ]
}
```

The `data` array contains many `a` and `b` and `c`. And no other kinds of objects.

If `count==0`, `data` should be an empty array `[]`.

I'm using https://github.com/hoxworth/json-schema to validate such JSON objects in Ruby.

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'json-schema'

p JSON::Validator.fully_validate('schema.json',"test.json")
```

The `schema.json` is:

```
{
  "type":"object",
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-03/schema",
  "required":true,
  "properties":{
     "count": { "type":"number", "id": "count", "required":true },
     "data": { "type":"array", "id": "data", "required":true,
       "items":[
           { "type":"object", "required":false, "properties":{ "a": { "type":"object", "id": "a", "required":true, "properties":{ "ax": { "type":"number", "id": "ax", "required":true } } } } },
           { "type":"object",  "required":false, "properties":{ "b": { "type":"object", "id": "b", "required":true, "properties":{ "bx": { "type":"number", "id": "bx", "required":true } } } } },
           { "type":"object",  "required":false, "properties":{ "c": { "type":"object", "id": "c", "required":true, "properties":{ "cx": { "type":"number", "id": "cx", "required":true } } } } }
       ]
     }
  }
}
```

But this for `test.json` will pass the validation while I suppose it should fail:

```
{
  "count":3,
  "data":[
      {
          "a":{"ax":1}
      },
      {
          "b":{"bx":2}
      },
      {
          "c":{"cx":2}
      },
      {
          "c": {"z":"aa"}
      }
   ]
}
```

And this as `test.json` will fail, while I suppose it should pass:

```
{
  "count":3,
  "data":[
      {
          "a":{"ax":1}
      },
      {
          "b":{"bx":2}
      }
   ]
}
```

Seems the wrong schema is validating that the `data` array contains `a,b,c` once.

What the right schema should be?

Comment: @Phrogz I have updated the question. You can see the example.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

From the [JSON schema spec](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-zyp-json-schema-03#section-5.5), section 5.5. items:

> When this attribute value is an array of schemas and the instance
> value is an array, each position in the instance array MUST conform
> to the schema in the corresponding position for this array.  This
> called tuple typing.

Your schema definition requires the first three elements of the array to be exactly those 'a', 'b' and 'c' elements. If `items` is left empty, any array element is allowed. Similarly, if `additionalItems` is left empty, any additional array element is allowed.

To get what you want, you need to specify `"additionalItems": false` and for the `items`, I think the following (somewhat shortened from your definitions) should work:

```
"items": {
  "type": [
     {"type":"object", "properties": {"a": {"type": "object", "properties": {"ax": { "type":"number"}}}}},
     {"type":"object", "properties": {"b": {"type": "object", "properties": {"bx": { "type":"number"}}}}},
     {"type":"object", "properties": {"c": {"type": "object", "properties": {"cx": { "type":"number"}}}}}
  ]
}
```

Comment: Is this the correct way to use "type" here? Wouldn't the value of "items" be the array instead?

Comment: @Confusion, sorry for opening this again, but the proposed solution doesn't work; so for example should I have more than 3 of the proposed objects in `data` array then the schema validation fails... any idea how to solve this?